# ngx-color Color Picker in Angular, not able to set width

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using the ngx-color Color Picker:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color#material

This is where I call the Color Picker and where I want to set the `width`

```
<div>
  <div class="flex-title">
    <h3 class='h3-btn'>Background Color</h3>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="openColorPicker()">
      <mat-icon>color_lens</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
  <jhi-bring-color [value]="this.color"></jhi-bring-color>
  <color-sketch *ngIf="isColorPickerOpen" color="#fff" width="200px" 
    (onChange)="changeOfColor($event)"></color-sketch>
</div>
```

Somehow it works and the Color Picker gets shown correctly:

[image]

Still I get the following error in the console:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> <color-sketch *ngIf="isColorPickerOpen" color="#fff" width=200px (onChange)="changeOfColor($event)">

I've tried these cases too: `width = "200"`, `width = 200`

Any idea why this error is shown, even though it is working?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Could you please add minimal reproducible example, f.e. a [StackBlitz](https://www.stackblitz.com), so it's easier to provide a solution for your question.

Comment: Check this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-color-picker . Weirdly there is no error shown here...

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, I guess that you have to write it like this:

```
<color-sketch *ngIf="isColorPickerOpen" color="#fff" [width]="200" 
              (onChange)="changeOfColor($event)"></color-sketch>
```

Without the brackets the value of the parameter will transferred as string inside the component.

Comment: Then your problem is not the `width` property.  From the documentation: `width - string | number`. So you may should close or edit your question and give us more info.

Answer (score 0):

After some time now I just took another color picker that looks similar.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker

It works fine and is simpler.

```
<div>
  <h3 class='h3-btn'>Background Color</h3>
  <input [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this " [width - String | Number, Pixel value for picker width](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color) ", you should write like this :

```
 <color-sketch *ngIf="isColorPickerOpen" [color]="#fff" [width]="'200px'" 
(onChange)="changeOfColor($event)"></color-sketch>
```